# access last datapoint in matlab cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell

If I have data in a 1-D vector (Y) in matlab, I can access the last value by calling 'end', such as answer = Y(end).  However, in my code, I am using a cell array to store a list of vectors of various lengths.  Each vector is one cell in a 1D cell array.  Is there some way in matlab to reference the last value of the vector stored in a specific cell array?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by writing `y{k}(end)` to grab the end of the kth item. Like this:

```
% Make some random vectors:
y1 = [ 1 2 3];
y2 = [ 1 5 9 12];
y3 = [9 48 2 1];

% create a cell array of them:
x = {y1, y2, y3};

% grab the end of the second vector:
k = 2;
x{k}(end)
```